# accessing security.txt from python

Tags: program, python, security

I am trying to integrate security.txt https://github.com/neodyme-labs/solana-security-txt into a project, and while from the repo it is clear how to access it from rust, I am at a loss as to how to do this in either python or javascript.

I can see the solana python library includes the parsing functionality for this, but I have no idea how to get to the program data from within python.

In rust you have to jump through a few hoops:

```
let program_account = client.get_account(&pubkey)


let program: UpgradeableLoaderState = bincode::deserialize_from(&program_account.data[..])?;

let program_data_address = if let UpgradeableLoaderState::Program {
programdata_address,
} = program
{
programdata_address
} else {
return Ok(());
};

let program_data_account = client.get_account(&program_data_address);


let offset = UpgradeableLoaderState::programdata_data_offset()?;
let program_data = &program_data_account.data[offset..];

let security_txt = solana_security_txt::find_and_parse(program_data)?;
println!("{}", security_txt);
```

but in python I really have no idea how to do all this stuff.. has anyone been able to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here's Solana labs official TS way: https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/master/src/utils/security-txt.ts

Unsure about Python.

Answer (score -1):

I would consider using the Solana.py as Python API library:
https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/

The particular security.txt processing is here (while I haven't tried):
https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/v0.29.0/src/solana/utils/security_txt.py